# Detect carriage return in UITextField

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios6, uitextfield

I have a app that enables the user to enter comments in a series of `UITextView`s. When complete the app generates a pdf report. Since the text entered varies in length the app needs to calculate where to position the text on the pdf.

What I can't figure out is how to detect if a return has been included in the text so that I can position the text on the pdf lower down. I need to scan the text when they are all complete and also when the page is returned to so it is not something that can be done as the key is pressed.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure that this is what I need. I want to know how many returns there are in the text field so that I can calculate the size of frame needed on the pdf. This is done after all the text fields are completed and not as the return key is pressed.

Comment: Are you wanting to know the number of newlines in a string?  That's easy enough, but might not tell reliably how big your frame needs to be as long lines might wrap.
How are you creating the PDF file? I'd have thought you'd be looking for something in the API for that to tell you how big a box you need for a given text.

Comment: @Rob - less haste on my part. You are right ... UITextViews thanks

Comment: @SteveWaddicor The method used works perfectly with solid text but gets thrown whenever new lines are introduced. So yes I am wanting to know how many new lines there are in a string. I am creating the pdf with a series of CGContextRef calls.

Comment: Counting how many times the user hit the return key is easy, but what if the user entered a really long line that wraps? That takes multiple lines, but the user didn't hit enter. The solution depends upon how you're rendering the text. With `CGContextShowText`? Or are you using UIKit control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

NSInteger numberOfLines = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count];

Comment: Totally perfect and pleasingly simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought that the real question is not how many newline characters are in the string, but rather how much space it takes to render the text (which includes not only how many times the user hit enter, but also how many times the text wrapped because it was too long to fit on single line).

If you're drawing text using something like [`drawInRect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect%3awithFont%3alineBreakMode%3a), that returns a `CGSize` that tells you how much space it took up, which is very convenient. Or if you want to know how much space it will take before rendering it, you can use [`sizeWithFont`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3alineBreakMode%3a). If you're writing the text with `CGContextShowText`, it's more complicated.

---

As Steve says you can create an array of these lines with `componentsSeparatedByString` and count the number of elements.

```
NSInteger count = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count];
```

Or you can enumerate the lines:

```
- (NSInteger)countLinesInString:(NSString *)string
{
    __block NSInteger count = 0;

    [string enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
        count++;
    }];

    return count;
}
```

Or you could actually count the number of newline characters:

```
- (NSInteger)countOccurrencesOfNewlineInString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSInteger count = 0;

    NSUInteger length = [string length];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if ([string characterAtIndex:i] == '\n')
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reply from Steve does just what I need though so using that.